# Opening Multiple windows of firefox in the same test case

Tags: webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver, .net

My question might sound very odd to you all but just wondering if this is possible for us.

Okay so I have written 10 cases for my login page in selenium using C# .net. But they take quite a lot of time to run one by one . SO I was wondering of there is a way that I can run few cases like 3-4 or may be more cases together . Like As I click on Run Selected Test it runs 3 cases together and then 3 and 3 and so on cause right now I have these 10 only but in future these cases might go upto 150 or something. SO just wondering if this is possible.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Rather than running multiple testcases at once, it might be possible to speed them up. If you have any `sleep()` calls, replace those with explicit waits to cut down on waiting time; and try running it in a headless browser to make it go faster; I recomment PhantomJS.

Comment: Hey Vincebowdren , thanks a lot for replying  I have used sleep only where my test were failing cause I was validating some messages rest everywhere else have used implicity wait ....Though thanks for recommending the Browser Idea will definitely give it a try.

Comment: Good luck with that - but definitely replace those sleeps with explicit waits. They'll do the job more reliably, and never waste any time when the browser runs quickly.

Comment: Cool just replacing that only ....thanks for the suggestions buddy.....

Answer (score 1):

Most test runners support running tests in parallel. I am not really into C#, but have a look at these posts:

- http://blog.yauheni.me/2009/12/design-of-selenium-tests-for-aspnet_19.html
- [Executing Unit Tests in parallel on a multi-CPU/core machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228171421/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx)
- http://blog.dmbcllc.com/running-selenium-in-parallel-with-any-net-unit-testing-tool/

Seems other SO users have had good experience with the Gallio test runner for .Net: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840028/parallel-testing-with-selenium-grid-using-c-sharp-unit-tests

Although it should be possible to run more then one test on a single machine. After you are getting more and more tests, you will want to run them for each check-in with a [continuous integration](https://www.jenkins.io/) / [build server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops) against a [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive) or a cloud grid like [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/platform/automation-tools/selenium) to speed up things even more.

Comment: Hey Niels thanks for replying . Will definitely give a try to your suggestion. Lets see which one works for me....

Answer (score 1):

I used NUnit originally when I wrote my C# cases.  Turns out NUnit did Not support parallel running of cases.

There is however [PNUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5) which does do what you want(now integrated into the latest NUnit but is still documented as PNUnit).  There is some documentation and examples [here](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/technical-articles/pnunit-parallel-nunit.html)